# Adding column to table with value from next row

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series

I have a table in PostgreSQL with a timestamp column, and I want to modify the table to have a second timestamp column and seed it with the value of the immediately successive timestamp. Is there a way to do this? The tables are fairly large, so a correlated subquery might kill the machine.

More concretely, I want to go from this to that:

```
+----+------+           +----+------+------+
| ts | data |           | ts | te   | data |
+----+------+           +----+------+------+
| T  | ...  |    -->    | T  | U    | ...  |
| U  | ...  |           | U  | V    | ...  |
| V  | ...  |           | V  | null | ...  |
+----+------+           +----+------+------+
```

Basically, I want to be able to hand point in time queries much better (i.e., give me the data for time X).

Comment: can you not select the successive timestamp when querying?why do you want to add it to the table?

Comment: @vkp I want to do queries of the form "select * from tab where x between tab.ts and tab.te" so I can find the value of data for a point in time. Doing the sort/limit on each query would be really slow.

Comment: you could to `x between tab.ts and tab.ts+1` for instance.That way you would eliminate the need for storing it in the table.

Comment: @vkp we don't know the difference between sucessove timestamps. Could be a nanosecond, could be a million nanos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I think you could just retrieve the timestamp at the query time, not storing it in the table, but if you're performing such action and think that this is what you need then:

You need to add that column to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN te timestamp;
```

Then perform an update feeding the value with the use of `LEAD` window function.

```
UPDATE tablename t
SET te = x.te
FROM (
  SELECT ts, lead(ts, 1) OVER (order by ts) AS te
  FROM tablename t2
  ) x
WHERE t.ts = x.ts
```

Here's an example of how it works using sample integer data: <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1f70f/1)</kbd>.

It will perform exactly the same for `timestamp` data type values.

Comment: Ah. thanks. Is lead/lag this a PostgreSQL thing? I remember it from Oracle extensions a few years ago. And how painful is this going to be? As long as it runs over a few hundred million rows in something resembling today, I'll be happy. Inserts from now will keep the table proper.

Comment: Also, is "OVER ..." needed? All the rows were inserted in timestamp order, but there is no primary key.

Comment: It's certainly going to take a while. Create an index on `ts` column for better performance. OVER is needed, because this is a window function. It's the syntax. No, it's not only PostgreSQL thing. It's used in SQLServer, Oracle ... Basically, window functions are ANSI SQL.

Comment: There is a B-Tree index on ts right now, but after I add te, I was going to give both BRIN indexes. Does that make the most sense?

Comment: I believe this is a totally different question. I think you should just try it out and decide.

Answer (score 0):

select ts,LEAD(ts) over(order by (select null)) as te,data from table_name