# How to take the date from the previous row

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to create new column named "End Date" and put there value from the next row but if the start date is the newest put there current date.

My version of MySQL db not support LAG and LEAD function.

Current state:

```
Start Date            User_id  
11/12/2019 9:26:00    user3    
29/12/2019 8:43:00    user2   
08/01/2020 10:52:00   user2    
10/02/2020 10:20:00   user1
```

What i want to achieve:

```
Start Date            User_id  End Date
11/12/2019 9:26:00    user3    29/12/2019 8:43:00
29/12/2019 8:43:00    user2    08/01/2020 10:52:00
08/01/2020 10:52:00   user2    10/02/2020 10:20:00 
10/02/2020 10:20:00   user1    28/05/2020 10:10:00
```

Comment: While remembering that rows in a relational database represent unordered sets, define 'next'

Comment: I guess this can shed some light on your question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36203097/adding-column-to-table-with-value-from-next-row

Comment: @JaredKarl if you meant the "lead" function, the version of the database that I use does not support.

Comment: It is recommended you upgrade to a later version of MySQL, if not, use MySQL's user variables as suggested here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49532456/mysql-find-the-time-difference-between-row-lag-and-lead-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to select the minimum `Start Date` that is greater than the current row's `Start Date` as the `End Date`, and if such a date doesn't exist, use `NOW()` instead:

```
SELECT *, 
       COALESCE((SELECT MIN(`Start Date`)
                 FROM data d2
                 WHERE d2.`Start Date` > d.`Start Date`),
                NOW()) AS `End Date`
FROM data d
ORDER BY `Start Date`
```

Output:

```
Start Date              User_id     End Date
2019-12-11 09:26:00     user3       2019-12-29 08:43:00
2019-12-29 08:43:00     user2       2020-01-08 10:52:00
2020-01-08 10:52:00     user2       2020-02-10 10:20:00
2020-02-10 10:20:00     user1       2020-05-28 07:51:24
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ceFxJzpBsKRMWguiGTWB3H/1)

Note I've assumed that the dates in your table are actually `datetime` values. If they are not (why not?) you will need to convert them first using [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Comment: What the query should look like, if we would like to consider within a given category, I tried to use the grouping function, but it did not help. Below is an extensive example:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7oPrZHi3zqbXuTDKGpsg6o/0

Comment: @Merix . . . That would be a different question and should be asked as a *new* question.  You should accept this answer before asking.

Comment: @Merix perhaps https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7oPrZHi3zqbXuTDKGpsg6o/1? If that's not what you're looking for, please ask a new question as Gordon suggests.